# How to use lists in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to write a program that gives me the count() and indexes of all vowels in a given string and stores it in a dictionary. So far this is what I have:

```
txt = "Text sample for vowel counting and indexing"

def ProcText(char,texto):
   lst_count=[]
   char_count = texto.count(str(char))
   lst_count.append(char_count)
   print(lst_count)

   lst_ind=[]
   char_ind = [i for (i,x) in enumerate(texto) if x == str(char)]
   lst_ind.append(char_ind)
   print(lst_ind)

ProcText("a",txt)
[2]
[[6, 31]]
```

So in the dictionary I would like to have something like this for every vowel:

```
{'a count' : 2 , 'a index' : 6,31}
```

Is there anyway Python allows this to happen? Using Python 3.6

Comment: So... you already have the values, but you need help putting them in a dict?

Comment: A few things here: (1) Why are you creating a list in `char_ind` and then appending that to an empty list? That's why you end up with `[[6, 31]]` instead of just `[6, 31]`, which I don't think is what you want. (2) Why are you using `str(char)` instead of just `char`? That `"a"` that you're passing in is already a `str`. Were you trying to turn it into something other than `"a"`? If so, explain what you wanted to happen, because it's not happening.

Comment: Anyway, I think what you want to do is to create a dict at the main level, then pass that dict into `ProcText` as another argument. Then, inside `ProcText`, you can do `d[f'{char} count'] = lst_count` and later `d[f'{char} index'] = lst_ind`. If that's _not_ what you want, explain what's wrong with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies but I was able find a solution on my own which I will share here hoping it will help others in the future.

The goal was to count all vowels in a string (upper and lower case makes no difference) and to also say the indexes of those vowels. All this information has to be stored in a dictionary.

So I defined a function to count all vowels in a string:

```
def ProcVogalCount(texto):
texto = texto.lower()
vogal = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
lst_count = []
for i in vogal:
    c = texto.count(i)
    lst_count.append(c)
return(lst_count)
```

Followed by another function that specifies the indexes for each vowel:

```
def ProcVogalInd(texto):
    texto = texto.lower()
    vogal = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
    lst_ind = []
    for i in vogal:
        indices = [a for (a,b) in enumerate(texto) if b == i]
        lst_ind.append(indices)
    return(lst_ind)
```

Finally I created one last function that takes the list returned by the other two funcions and zipped everything into two separate dictionaries:

```
def DicionarioVogais(texto):
    lst1 = ProcVogalCount(texto)
    keys1 = ['A cont:','E cont:','I cont:','O cont:','U cont:']
    dic1 = dict(zip(keys1,lst1))
    lst2 = ProcVogalInd(texto)
    keys2 = ['A ind:','E ind:','I ind:','O ind:','U ind:']
    dic2 = dict(zip(keys2,lst2))
    print(dic1)
    print(dic2)
```

So the end result of calling the last function on a string is something like:

```
{'A cont:': 6, 'E cont:': 13, 'I cont:': 5, 'O cont:': 4, 'U cont:': 3} {'A ind:': [0, 30, 35, 38, 44, 76], 'E ind:': [6, 9, 12, 18, 20, 24, 48, 53, 56, 58, 63, 70, 73], 'I ind:': [3, 45, 50, 65, 68], 'O ind:': [15, 27, 42, 77], 'U ind:': [2, 34, 62]}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comments already received: The count method iterates through your sentence anyway, but you could do the same thing in an easier way since the number of indices will give you the number of occurrences.  What about:

```
txt = "Text sample for vowel counting and indexing"
vowel = "a"
vowel_dict = {}

def proc_text(char,texto):
   char_ind = [i for (i,x) in enumerate(texto) if x == char]
   return (len(char_ind), char_ind)

result = (proc_text(vowel,txt))

vowel_dict[str(vowel) + " count"] = result[0]
vowel_dict[str(vowel) + " indices"] = result[1]

print(my_dict)
```

since you can return a tuple with Python, allowing you to return more than one object.  I am sure that you can refactor this to achieve what you want in a more succinct way, as suggested by abarnert.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with list comprehensions using the following two steps:

```
indexes = [(v,[ i for i,c in enumerate(txt) if c == v]) for v in "aeiou" ]
vDict = dict( [("%s index"%v,a) for v,a in indexes] + [("%s count"%v,len(a)) for v,a in indexes] )

# dict == {'a index': [6, 31], 'e index': [1, 10, 19, 38], 'i index': [27, 35, 40], 'o index': [13, 17, 23], 'u index': [24], 'a count': 2, 'e count': 4, 'i count': 3, 'o count': 3, 'u count': 1}
```

but I believe you will find the choice of keys for your dictionary may be difficult to use afterward.  I would suggest a dictionary with letters as keys and index lists as values. You can easily get the count using len() on the index list for any given letter.

```
vDict = { v:[ i for i,c in enumerate(txt) if c == v] for v in "aeiou" }

# vDict = {'a': [6, 31], 'e': [1, 10, 19, 38], 'i': [27, 35, 40], 'o': [13, 17, 23], 'u': [24]}
```

This gives you an entry in the dictionary for every vowel even when the string doesn't contain any (i.e. an empty list of indexes)

If you only want keys for letters that are actually in the string, you could do this:

```
cDict = { k:[ i for i,c in enumerate(txt) if c == k] for k in set(txt) }
```

This will give you entries in the dictionary only for letters that are actually present.  You can then filter the keys on vowels only (or consonants only) as needed.